# After I log in, one letter (lowercase t) isn't working?

Tags: keyboard

As weird as it sounds, my 't' key works for login (it is part of my password) but once I am logged in it doesn't work in lower case in any app or at the command line.  I have rebooted twice.

I am using a toshiba z835 ultrabook.

The keyboard know the key is being pressed - the backlight comes on and if I keep it pressed I see flickering indicating that's it's being detected, but no 't' appears.

Uppercase T is working ok! Plus when i put caps lock on and do shift-T I actually get a lower case 't' !  Obviously can't work normally with that.

Comment: Probably some other application that you have recently installed is using 't' as a hotkey, I do not know how to check which application, but the behaviour that you are experiencing looks like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had remapped it by mistake in Ubuntu Tweaks.